# Microchip XC8: multi-byte assignment with reverse endian

Tags: optimization, hi-tech-compiler, xc8

Most, if not all, chips targeted by XC8 process one byte at a time.  To assign a value from one multi-byte variable to another, it has to load the first 8 bits from the source into WREG and store them into the first 8 bits of the destination and then do that again with the next 8 bits.  At the assembly level, this makes it trivial to adjust the endianness at the same time simply by reordering the load instructions or the store instructions (but not both).

But I can't seem to make XC8 do that.  I've tried various combinations of shifting by 8, or'ing components, and'ing with masks, etc., and the smallest assembly code I can get comes from a straight assignment followed by an xor swap:

```
union
{
    unsigned int i;
    struct
    {
        unsigned char lo;
        unsigned char hi;
    };
} address;

    address.i = Packet->dest_addr;
    address.hi ^= address.lo;   //xor swap: valA ^ valB = diff (bitwise difference, not arithmetic)
    address.lo ^= address.hi;   //xor swap: valA ^ diff = valB
    address.hi ^= address.lo;   //xor swap: valB ^ diff = valA
```

I would think that the pointer source would help or make no difference, depending on whether it took advantage of the pointer inc/decrement instructions, but it insists on recalculating the pointer for each byte except for a direct assignment like this.

Am I missing something?

(I included the hi-tech tag because XC8 is descended from Hi-Tech after Microchip bought it.  Maybe there's an old trick from there that still works?)

Answer (score 2):

First, if you care about the machine instructions, use assembler.

Second, if you want to use a different encoding scheme than what the compiler uses for a multi-byte integer, then you might as well declare it as a byte array in the first place.  The compiler won't be able to operate on a byte-flipped integer properly anyway.

Comment: I was wanting to avoid inlining this.  I just wanted it to be a little more concise in C without horribly de-optimizing it.  The reason to endian-swap in this case is that the incoming Packet already has it backwards and I need to correct it before I use it.  But that detail shouldn't matter just to make the tool work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have xc8.

Extending your code:

```
union Fubar
{
    unsigned int i;
    struct
    {
        unsigned char lo;
        unsigned char hi;
    };
};

    union Fubar address;
    unsigned int da = Packet->dest_addr;
    address.hi = ((union Fubar)da).lo;
    address.lo = ((union Fubar)da).hi;
```

or

```
    union Fubar address;
    address.hi = ((union Fubar)Packet->dest_addr).lo;
    address.lo = ((union Fubar)Packet->dest_addr).hi;
```

Isn't one of those smaller?

I'd expect the second one to be slower, because it reloads stuff, if any part of `Packet->dest_addr` is `volatile`.

Edit (Even Uglier Alert):

```
union Fubar address;
unsigned char* const dp = &((unsigned char)Packet->dest_addr);
address.hi = dp[0];    // may need to swap the two destinations,
address.lo = dp[1];    // hi, lo, to get required byte order
```

That *might* help let the compiler do a better job.

Comment: Your first one is probably shorter by 2 instructions, but it uses a temp variable, which may not be all bad.  (My xor swap takes a total of six plus the initial assignment; your first one would take four.)

Comment: I would expect your second one to recalculate the pointer simply because it appears a second time.  (Stupid, I know, but that's the pattern that I see in the assembly listing.)  Good thinking, though.

Comment: @AaronD - IMHO it's hard to second guess a compiler, especially for the sort of complex trade-offs small PICs seem to need to squeeze the maximum from them.

Comment: Closer look at the original code (I posted a simplified version), Packet is actually a detailed structure itself that includes the same union for dest_addr.  Using hi and lo of that does indeed recalculate the pointer.

Comment: @AaronD - in that case, it might be worth taking a pointer, and using it. I am assuming xc8 isn't super smart, so rather than use *p++, try p[0] and p[1]. I guess all are worth trying.

Comment: I would avoid using pointers on a PIC 16 if code efficiency is a primary concern.  After all, you're just copying two bytes with the source and destination addresses known at link time.  Pointers shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Actually, the address in the pointer isn't known at link time.  That's why it's a pointer.  New data comes in as a generic bunch of bytes into a circular buffer, and the Packet pointer is set for the next in line to be processed.  The packet structure is a higher-level construct than the communications.

Comment: If the compiler is smart, and the pointer *is* to a fixed address, pointers should not be used. That is partly why I used `dp[0]`, so the compiler could see what more of what is happening. However, you have caused me to thin of another technique, which I'll think about while eating food.

Comment: I tried that just now, and it still recalculates the pointer for each byte.  More good thinking though.

Comment: @AaronD - Are you using volatile on the pointer which can be 'cast away' here? Are you using maximum optimisation? Can you use a #pragma to tell the compiler to make more generous assumptions about pointers? If not, grab the word. I hear food calling ...

Comment: The pointer comes pre-set as an argument to the function that this is in, like this: void foo(struct pkt* Packet);  There are two choices for optimization: +speed and +space.  I'm using +speed.  I'm using #pragmas for other purposes, but I don't know of any for this one.